# Actual data in a digitally signed document

Tags: encryption, sign, digital

In a digitally signed document, I understand that its the HASH value of the actual data that is encrypted by the private key of sender!
with that digitally signed doc contains actual data, encrypted hash, and the public key of sender.

while this is transmitted to receiver(s), does actual data transmits in an un-encrypted format? If that is the case then any one could at least read the data seamlessly! How is that safe-gaurded?

Comment: Just like in year 1820 it is not possible to verify a signature on a document in year 2020 without having the actual document. That's kind of the definition of signature. Of course there are more complicated protocols that combine encryption and authentication to achieve various security goals.

Comment: my question in other words :- while a digitally signed document is sent, does it ensure only authenticity and integrity; while Confidentiality is not ensured! is that a correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.